# combine and group rows from 2 dfs

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dfs, which I want to combine as the following:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2], "b":['A','B'], "c":[3,2]})


df2 = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3, 4], "b":['A','A','A','B','B', 'B','C','D'], "c":[3, None,None,2,None,None,None,None]})

Output: 
    a   b   c
   1   A   3.0
   1   A   NaN
   1   A   NaN
   2   B   2.0
   2   B   NaN
   2   B   NaN
```

I had an earlier version of this question that only involved df2 and was solved with

```
df.groupby(['a','b']).filter(lambda g: any(~g['c'].isna()))
```

but now I need to run it only for rows that appear in df1 (df2 contains rows from df1 but some extra rows which I want to *not* be included.

Thanks!

Comment: what's the expected output?

Comment: Hi @enke the expected output is in the first part of my question. Sorry if it wasn't clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn the `indicator` on with `merge`

```
out = df2.merge(df1,indicator=True,how='outer',on=['a','b'])
Out[91]: 
   a  b  c_x  c_y     _merge
0  1  A  3.0  3.0       both
1  1  A  NaN  3.0       both
2  1  A  NaN  3.0       both
3  2  B  2.0  2.0       both
4  2  B  NaN  2.0       both
5  2  B  NaN  2.0       both
6  3  C  NaN  NaN  left_only
7  4  D  NaN  NaN  left_only

out = out[out['_merge']=='both']
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you could `merge`:

```
out = df2.merge(df1[['a','b']])
```

or you could use chained `isin`:

```
out1 = df2[df2['a'].isin(df1['a']) & df2['b'].isin(df1['b'])]
```

Output:

```
   a  b    c
0  1  A  3.0
1  1  A  NaN
2  1  A  NaN
3  2  B  2.0
4  2  B  NaN
5  2  B  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks@enke. This solution worked, but for some reason, I'm still missing some rows from df1, and their "sister rows" that should come from df2. Not sure why.. I'm trying to explore it.

Comment: @RanAntes because we’re testing for df2.isin(df1), if there are values in df1 that aren’t df2, they are not selected.

Comment: It's ok now @enke.i used the merge, and found that the problem was that on of the keys (date) didn't have the same format for all rows in the original csv. Solved now thanks so much